# How do I print all labels that are defined in a sphinx project?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I would like to print a list of all labels that are defined throughout all sphinx documents in my project including labels that I defined manually like this

```
.. _mylabel:
```

and also labels that sphinx generates automatically such as :ref:`genindex` and :ref:`search`.

For large projects I often forget how I spelled certain labels (Did I call it "examples", "Examples" or "sect-examples"?). If I could just print out all labels that are defined in any of the files, I could look at that list and recognize the name without checking the individual file each time I want to reference something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `grep` and just search using a regex:

```
grep '^\.\. _' path/to/docs/* -r
```

Comment: Using `grep` is a perfect method to get all the labels that I define manually, but it does reveal those that sphinx automatically defines, such as "search", "genindex", ...

Comment: I found the solution to my question that gives me strictly all labels as I asked in the questions. Nevertheless, I decided to accept your answer, since this is MUCH simpler and probably covers 99.9 % of all use cases.

Answer (score 9):

When sphinx is running, it saves information about the documents that it parses in a file called `environmment.pickle`. This includes the labels of all references that are defined in the project, both explicit in the rst files and those set automatically when running sphinx.
This is sorted by domain. Here is the way in which I can find all labels in the "Standard Domain" (`std`):

Python 3:

```
import pickle
with open("environment.pickle", "rb") as f:
    dat = pickle.load(f)
dat.domaindata['std']['labels'].keys()
```

Python 2:

```
import cPickle
dat = cPickle.load(file('environment.pickle'))
dat.domaindata['std']['labels'].keys()
```

This works equally well for other sphinx domains.
You will see that the label `modindex` (for the python module index) is always defined, even if the module index is not generated (Links to this will be dead).

Sphinx defines only very few labels (`search`, `genindex`, `modindex`), so the method stated here answers my original question, but is probably only useful for debugging of sphinx extensions. It can also be useful to inspect labels generated by [sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html).

Comment: has shown a good possible solution in case if you want to get all the labels. "dat.domaindata['std']['labels'].keys()" gives all the labels pointed to headings, figures, tables... In order to get the labels pointed to paragraphs, you have to use "dat.domaindata['std']['anonlabels'].keys()".